# Placing “through” after a subject

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

I wrote this sentence and my teacher underlined it as a mistake because I didn’t add a verb before the preposition “through”

> - Children **through** getting exposure to media and listening to daily news can determine what the wrong and right things are.

My teacher told me to put a verb following **children**, and he referred to the mistake as a sentence structure.

Why should I put a verb before through?

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher appears to have misparsed the sentence, and not recognised "through getting exposure to media and listening to daily news" as a prepositional phrase acting as a complement to "determine".

What you have is grammatical, but awkward and confusing (it seems to have confused your teacher). It would be clearer if you set off the prepositonal phrase with commas before or after (which would make it parenthetical), or else moved it after the verb.

Answer (score 2):

I think the teacher is mistaken, based on the account in the question. I see "thorugh" here as much the same as "by means of". If I were writing this I might well use dashes to set off  "through getting exposure to media and listening to daily news", as it is a prepositional phrase. it explains **how** children are able to "determine what the wrong and right things are". I can't see what verb could possibly follow "children" to make this a better sentence with an essentially similar meaning.

The sentence could be recast as:

> Through getting exposure to media and listening to daily news, children  can determine what the wrong and right things are.

also, the phrase "the right and wrong things" seems a bit awkward, but context might help that. Right and wrong in what way? Things to do? things to say? The sentence does not specify. But perhaps other sentences in the paragraph do.